# Urllib2 POST request results in 409 conflict error

Tags: python, django, nginx, urllib2, gunicorn

I am calling google's pubsubhubbub publisher at http://pubsubhubbub.appspot.com via Django's view. I want to fetch all the youtube uploads feeds using it. I am sending a 'post' request to it using urllib2.Request, and I get 409 conflict error. I have properly setup callback url, and if I try to post the same request using: `python manage shell` it works perfectly fine. I am using nginx server as a proxy to gunicorn instance at the production server. What could possibly be wrong. Thanks in advance.

```
>>> response.request
<PreparedRequest [POST]>
>>> response.request.headers
{'Content-Length': u'303', 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded', 'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, compress', 'Accept': '*/*', 'User-Agent': 'python-requests/1.2.0 CPython/2.6.6 Linux/2.6.18-308.8.2.el5.028stab101.3'}
>>> response.request.body
'hub.verify=sync&hub.topic=http%3A%2F%2Fgdata.youtube.com%2Ffeeds%2Fapi%2Fusers%2FUCVcFOpBmJqkQ4v6Bh6l1UuQ%2Fuploads%3Fv%3D2&hub.lease_seconds=2592000&hub.callback=http%3A%2F%2Fhypedsound.cloudshuffle.com%2Fhub%2F19%2F&hub.mode=subscribe&hub.verify_token=subscribe7367add7b116969a44e0489ad9da45ca8aea4605'
```

Request body, headers are same for both requests generated.

Here is the nginx config file:
http://dpaste.org/bOwHO/

Comment: You should download Wireshark (http://www.wireshark.org/) to inspect the packets that are being sent/received for the two different calls, to see what is different about them.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I was using TransactionMiddleware which does not commit to db when model.save() is called, which was creating the issue.